# Is there a whoami to find the current group I'm logged in as?

Tags: linux, users, group

I'm trying to find my current logged in group without wanting to use newgrp to switch.

Comment: Generally you belong to several groups, which you can simply find with `groups`!

Answer (score 122, accepted):

I figured I can use the following.

```
id -g
```

To get all the groups I belong

```
id -G
```

And to get the actual names, instead of the ids, just pass the flag `-n`.

```
id -Gn
```

This last command will yield the same result as executing

```
groups
```

Comment: and id -G to the other groups you belong to.

Comment: Add *-n* to see group names instead of GIDs: *id -gn* and *id -Gn* respectively.

Answer (score 34):

To get group name needed one more flag:
`id -g -n`